# Testing Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know what's the best approach to test a Fragment that is loaded inside an Activity in Android. Maybe the best solution is using [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html), but I'd rather JUnit Activity tests. This is a piece of code of a test:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testBasic() {
    mQuestionPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    QuestionsFragment fragment =
            (QuestionsFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(mQuestionPager.getCurrentItem());

    ListView lv = (ListView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.questionslistview);

    lv.smoothScrollToPosition(9);
}
```

The Activity is a FragmentActivity that contains a ViewPager that load several instances of a Fragment, containing different contents.

I'd like to test the scrolling of the ListView to perform further tests with that, but when I try to get fragment.getView() a NullPointerException is raised because it seems that the root view of the fragment hasn't been inflated yet.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, and it was pretty logical. You just need to provide methods to access the Fragment from the Activity, and from the Fragment to its contents. Don't forget to access UI elements from the UI thread. The following is a working example:

First, the test (well, it's not a test, but a helper, but it's ok to illustrate the case, you'll see why):

```
private void checkListViewItemsShown(int expectedItems) {
        QuestionsFragment fragment = mActivity.getCurrentQuestionsFragment();
        final ListView lv = fragment.getQuestionsListView();
        assertNotNull(lv);
        assertEquals("The ListView should be visible", View.VISIBLE, lv.getVisibility());
        int actualItems = lv.getCount();
        assertEquals("The number of items shown was not expected", expectedItems, actualItems);
    }
```

The following is how I access the fragment from the activity. In this case I have a ViewPager and each Page is a different Fragment:

```
public QuestionsFragment getCurrentQuestionsFragment() {
    return (QuestionsFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(mQuestionPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

Finally, this is how I make the ListView available from the tests:

```
public ListView getQuestionsListView() {
    return (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.questionslistview);
}
```

There's no magic clue, as you can see. Now if you'd like to perform an action with the listView obtained:

```
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv.requestFocus();
            lv.smoothScrollToPosition(CommonConstants.QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE - 1);
        }
    });
```